# Spring Boot Actuator Logback Metric with custom Filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer, spring-logback

I have a custom filter configured that is filtering log messages as expected by returning `FilterReply.DENY`. However the Actuator metrics for `logback.events` still count Log Events for those denied events. How do I configure my app to ignore those events?

```
<springProfile name="prod">
   <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
       <filter class="com.example.config.CustomEventFilter"/>
   </appender>
</springProfile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with `Filters` working on an appender level. However I solved the issue using a `TurboFilter` as suggested in https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/3667#issuecomment-1449403371.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if you are using the latest version and if `MetricsTurboFilter` is [registered](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/logging/LogbackMetrics.java) after your custom filter in your app? If so and you still have this issue, could you please open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: The version used with `Spring Boot 2.7.8` is `1.9.7` but it was the same behavior with `1.10.4`. How can I check the filters registered? The `turboFilterList` of `loggerContext` only contains `MetricsTurboFilter`. My `CustomEventFilter` is attached to the `ConsoleAppender` at `loggerContext.root.aai.appenderList[0].fai.filterList`.

Comment: With a debugger but I think that's what you did. Please open an issue with a reproducer.

Comment: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/3667 Thanks for the reply so far