# Why are Logback metrics increased for filtered logging events?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, micrometer

I have an application with configured Logback Evaluator Filter to exclude certain log messages from Hibernate using the `JaninoEventEvaluator`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="false">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
                <expression>return logger.equals("org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper") &amp;&amp;
                    (message.contains("duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"the_constraint_name\"") ||
                    message.contains("SQLState: 23505"));</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>


    <logger name="com.mypackage" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>


</configuration>
```

This works fine and the `duplicate key violates unique constraint` message is not logged.

Problem is that every time this happens, the Logback metric `logback.events` is increased, so according to the application metrics it looks like an error has occurred anyway.

Reson for this appears to be in  `io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.logging.MetricsTurboFilter` where these counters are [defined](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/067f4c3849fed1a289293d034caf780e8113d8e8/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/logging/LogbackMetrics.java#L138). If I'm reading the Logback documentation correctly, Turbo Filters are called "... each and every time a logging request is issued": https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#TurboFilter.

So my question is if there is any way to configure Micrometer/Spring Boot to not increase this error metric when this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar to [Spring Boot Actuator Logback Metric with custom Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088934/spring-boot-actuator-logback-metric-with-custom-filter)

Could you please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524785/971735) there and if you were not able to fix this based on it, could you please open an issue on GitHub?